# Calling method from within own class method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method called `LoginAttempt:` with the following class header:

```
- (IBAction)LoginAttempt:(UIButton *)sender
```

and I'm trying to call this method in the same class' `textFieldShouldReturn:` method like this:

```
[self LoginAttempt:(SENDER TYPE HERE)];
```

The problem is, I can't figure out what to call where I put 'SENDER TYPE HERE', running Xcode 5, iOS 7.1 I believe, and Xcode has a suggestion:  `(UIButton *)`, like I'm supposed to enter a UIButton as the sender. Sorry if this is really amateur, but I'm really new to Objective-C and C, so I'm not really sure what it wants.

I have tried self.self, changing the cast on sender in LoginAttempt to `id`, and just taking away the (UIButton *).

How do I successfully call `LoginAttempt:`?

Answer (score 1):

You can always just pass `nil`.

```
[self LoginAttempt:nil];
```

As the method is an `IBAction`, it's designed to be hooked up to a IB element and the `sender` argument will be a reference to the UI element that called the method.  You can send anything or nothing though.  Most likely, your implementation of the method doesn't even use the `sender` variable, so sending `nil` is more than fine.

And by the way, method names should begin with lowercase letters...